# Javascript validation error not valid value N/A

Tags: javascript, asp.net

When User Enter N/A value With and without space in between display error message using javascript

if user enter "N/A" ," N/A","N/A "," N/A "," N / A ","N /A ",etc
Any were Write N/A error message using javascript

Comment: ...What's your question? I'm really unsure what you mean here.

Comment: Nobody can help you if you don't provide an understandable problem and relate that problem to some code

Comment: If textbox value is "N/A" with space and without space display error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the string "N/A" is without anything leading or tailing you can do the following

```
var na = contentOfYourTextbox;
if(!na.match(/^N\s*[/]\s*A$/)){
  alert("I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.");
} else {
  // do whatever you have plannned to do when the user entered "N/A"
}
```

Comment: In case User enter N/A////// Display validation error

Comment: Yes, that string counts as an error. If you want to accept everything starting with `N/A` you have to delete the dollarsign in the regular expression.